# Vue Multiselect Data Binding

Tags: javascript, binding, autocomplete, vue.js, multi-select

I finally discovered an outstanding searchable select Vue component, https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect .

The only problem is, if you feed it an array of objects as options, the data binds to the entire object, not just the value.

Here is the issue which oddly was created 8 hours before my quest began:

https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect/issues/263

I must be missing something.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like that's how I would expect it to work. What problem does that create for you?

Comment: I also would prefer they had a solution for binding just the value back to the model, but it doesn't seem to support this. I'm running into a similar problem when using this with name/value pairs. I only want to post back the value, and the name is simply used as a label/display. I just used some javascript to figure out the value from the vue-multiselect component and map it to a variable in my code. It's a hack, but it works.

Answer (score 9):

Filter options and use custom label.

```
let types = [
  {id: 1, name: "john"},
  {id: 2, name: "steve"}
];

<multiselect 
  v-model="rule.id" 
  :options="types.map(type => type.id)" 
  :custom-label="opt => types.find(x => x.id == opt).name">
</multiselect>
```

For more check this github [issue](https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/issues/432#issuecomment-336955788).

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of vue-multiselect,
it shows that:

- Array of available options: Objects, Strings or Integers.
- If array of objects, visible label will default to option.label.
- If `labal` prop is passed, label will equal option['label']
- @type {Array}
  */
  options: {
  type: Array,
  required: true
  },

So, it's expected to bind to entire object of provided list, and the option may be assigned to the object's label property, like this:

[...
{
  label: "option1",otherdata..
},
{
  label: "option2",otherdata..
},
]...

Answer (score 0):

I created an **object** that receive the **object** selected in a **vue-multiselect**, and then a send using '@input' calling a function **"listaCidades"** that will send to my api only the "**id**", may be this help you:

```html
<multiselect                          
  v-model="estadoSelecionado"
  :options="listaEstado"
  :multiple="false"      
  label="descricao"
  track-by="descricao"
  :preselect-first="false"
  @input="listaCidades(estadoSelecionado.id)"
></multiselect>
```

```js
listaCidades(idEstado){
  //send my id selected to my api
  this.$http
    .get(this.$urlAPI + "/cidade/lista/" + idEstado, {
      headers: {
        authorization: "Bearer " + this.usuario.token
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.data.status) {            
        this.listaCidade = response.data.listaCidade;            
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With latest version `vue-multiselect` this work for me

```
<multiselect
  v-model="store_front_id"
  track-by="id"
  label="name"
  :options="storefronts.map(i => i.id)"
  :searchable="false"
>
  <template slot="singleLabel" slot-scope="props">
    <span class="option__title">{{ getStoreFrontName(props) }}</span>
  </template>
  <template slot="option" slot-scope="props">
    <span class="option__small">{{ getStoreFrontName(props) }}</span>
  </template>
</multiselect>

computed: {
    ...mapState('storefront', ['storefronts']),
},
methods: {
    getStoreFrontName(props) {
        return this.storefronts.find(i => i.id === props.option).name
    },
}
```